# Trouble integrating Azure mobile services into Windows Universal App in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I am currently building a Universal Windows Platform app, using an Azure database. Think all Microsoft stuff.

I created a mobile service and database through the official manage.windowsazure site. There I got 3 steps to follow, in order to add Azure :

> 1. Download a personalized Mobile Service project and add it to your project
> 2. Connect app and store data in it:
>
> > Add **WindowsAzure.MobileServices** Nuget Package to the project.
> >
> > Add a public **MobileServiceClient** variable to **app.xaml.cs**
> >
> > Add a sample ToDoItem class to your project
> >
> > Use the Mobile Services client library to store data in the mobile service
>
> 3. Publish app to the cloud

Now, I downloaded that starter project and put it in one of the UWP's sub folders, cause it has to be incorporated in Visual Studio Online's version control, when I commit the whole thing. Screenshot of the folder structure is here, in case it's important: https://i.stack.imgur.com/09z4o.png

Then I added the WindowsAzure.MobileServices package to both my project and the add-on Service project, just to be sure. I also added that variable, no problem. Though I didn't add that ToDoItem class, nor store any data already, since it wasn't necessary yet. Ditto for the publishing.

Now the problem: When I try to build the project or open any of the Service files, I get a huge load of errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLLpG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmX8c.png

Does anyone know where I went wrong? Did I forget something important? Do I have to add one project as reference to another? Or add another reference to the Service project?

Comment: Can you post a screengrab of your project files/solution in visual studio?

Comment: sounds like you may need to update all the namespaces

Comment: @jdruid here is a screenshot of the solution explorer: http://i.imgur.com/VvkY7sJ.png    and Swilko, what exactly do I have to update in this case? I don't think I understand

Comment: can you expand references...do you see mobile services in there?
What about just creating a new project and adding the package again?

Comment: Alright, I took screenshots of the references. In the main project everything seems to be working fine. Though in the Service project there seem to be multiple 'danger' sign icons. When I hover over them, nothing gets displayed though. As can be seen here: http://imgur.com/a/I6uTG      I tried creating a new UWP project and adding Azure's Service project there, but I got the same errors.

Comment: whats the service project?

Comment: WP_travelApp_G6_Service the one with the danger signs at its references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it. I downloaded the entire project from Azure and modified that to my needs. So basically remake the whole project.

Comment: to piggy back on my own answer. If you don't want to start from scratch, you can also try the reverse. Add your main project to the Service add-on. In case anyone else ever stumbled upon this in the future.